# How to efficiently backtrace segment fault using lldb?

Tags: c, lldb

I'm a newbie to LLDB (well, actually a newbie to most command-line tools). When I was following this extremely [easy and helpful article](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html) to backtrace segment fault error, I found my output on Mac OS X 10.10 using LLDB is different from the output by the author who was using gdb as debugger.

To make the problem clearer.
After I run the same code in the above article using lldb, met the segment fault error, and used the `bt` command of lldb, I got this message.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x208541, 0x00007fff8869a05a libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Unknown + 186, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff8869a05a libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Unknown + 186
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8fc08866 libsystem_c.dylib`fgets + 243
    frame #2: 0x0000000100000f34 sf`main + 68
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8e6535c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Since I named my executable file as "sf" (short for segment fault), I followed the idea in the article and used `f 2` command.

Now things went wrong, because I got this message.

```
frame #2: 0x0000000100000f34 sf`main + 68
sf`main:
    0x100000f34 <+68>: leaq   0x5f(%rip), %rdi          ; "%s\n"
    0x100000f3b <+75>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rsi
    0x100000f3f <+79>: movq   %rax, -0x20(%rbp)
    0x100000f43 <+83>: movb   $0x0, %al
```

It seems like assembly language and is really unhelpful compared with the C language given by gdb as shown in the above article, which is:

```
#3  0x80484b2 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffffaf4) at segfault.c:10
10        fgets(buf, 1024, stdin)
```

So my question is that can I get a C language backtrace using LLDB?

Comment: It appears you did not build your program with debugging symbols. If you did, it would look [something like this](http://pastebin.com/NDxx37Zk). built with clang 3.6 on Mac OS X 10.10.3 *with debugging symbols enabled* (-g switch).

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `-g` flag when you compile.  Also, I would recommend using the `-O0` flag, which tells your compiler to perform minimal optimizations.  With more aggressive optimizations, you can get strange behavior in the debugger.  Usually when I try and track down seg faults and similar errors I find the conditional breakpoint and watchpoint to be the most useful of commands.  You can set a conditional breakpoint at a line number by doing `breakpoint set --file <filename> --line <line number> --condition '<some C expression>'`.  Watchpoints can be set with `w s e -- <address>` where `<address>` is the location to be watched.